# VB.NET Write yields #ERROR 448#

Tags: windows, vb.net

I have a bit of ported code. It was automatically converted from VB6 to VB.NET. Now when if finally compiles, it produces output files with some values replaced with literal `#ERROR 448#`.

I will eventually find out what's the problem, but I just wonder, if anyone knows what does this error mean. VB's `Write` function is used.

Comment: Ha-ha, I couldn't find it yet. Lurking for the right piece now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it as simple as trying to write a variable set to `Nothing` makes `#ERROR 448#` written to the file. Strange that [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.writeline.aspx) is not telling you this.

Answer (score 0):

You are tryng to WRITE a null value or other unacceptable value to a file. Earlier versions of BASIC just ignored the WRITE request. MSDN should be telling you about this.